# Trying to manually remove a file from Multifile upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Examples)
and I have the following:

```
$(function(){ // wait for document to load
    $('#attachFiles').MultiFile({
        list: '#attList',
        STRING: { remove: '<img src="cross.gif" title="Remove this attachment" border="0">' },
        afterFileAppend: function(element, value, master_element) {
            $(".amount").each(function(){
                var i       = $(this).attr("i");
                var curVal  = $("#attachment_" + i).val();
                if($("#attachment_" + i).is(":checked") && curVal == "X") {
                    $("#attachment_" + i).attr("value", value);
                    $("#attachment_" + i).attr("title", "Attachment " + value + " linked");
                    aCounter++;
                };
            });
            if(aCounter==0) {
                alert("You need to select...");
                //Remove should be here
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If I add a file named test.pdf then one named test2.pdf my goal is to automatically remove test2.pdf if my aCounter variable is 0 (that would mean the user did not check off any additional check boxes named attachment_#.

I can't seem to figure out how to remove just the file that was added.
If I understand correctly, the value of the file that I add gets added to id="attachfiles" which is a

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" id="attachFiles" class="file" size="1" accept="pdf|jpg|jpeg">
```

So I'm assuming I should be able to somehow remove the most recently added item somehow.
Any assistance or guidance would be great.

Comment: I've never used the plugin, but from the looks of the documentation you won't find what you're looking for built-in. Luckily the license allows you to modify the source, so I would get familiar with the plugin's source (it's not that bad) and add a method to remove a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery Multiple File plugins that I've used do NOT use some array to hold the set of files.  They use a series of

```
<input type="file" ... style="position:absolute; left:-3000px;" /> 
<input type="file" ... style="position:absolute; left:-3000px;" />
```

elements that are hidden after the user selects a file.  The displayed input element is replaced with a new one.  This also seems to be the case with your plugin.  You should be able to find the most recent file by doing some selector

```
$("#mydiv input[type='file']").last()
```

or something similar and removing it from the DOM.

You can probably also do a trigger('click') on the appropriate delete button.

Comment: I see how this page might cause some confusion: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Uploading  I believe on the Javascript side of things, there are several input elements as I've described above.  Once it is processed on the PHP side (which I know nothing about) it is viewed as an array of files.  So, while you're activating the plugin on that single input element, many are actually being generated.

Comment: Thanks - I think that's the direction I'm going to head (your first suggestion) - I'll be back once I try it all out.